# Page load effects - each new page slides in from a different direction (... as a single page site using scrollTo)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide, smooth-scrolling

Is there a way to make each pages load by sliding in from a different direction? (X and Y axis)

Like in this example: [single page site scrolling to div](http://www.tendancescommunication.com/wip/)

The reason for this is because it doesnt work on iPads/iPhone (they don't support fixed element, the whole page scrolls). I figured if there was a header menu and a footer maybe I could achieve this effect.

Then, mobiles would render a regular web page. Also, I guess it would be easier for the client to manage things via a CMS.

Thanks in advance.

ive d.

...Again, sorry for my lousy English ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can serve different css to a mobile device by using the ="handheld" switch.

I suggest looking into User Agent Detection, such with PHP similar to:

```
<? if (
 stristr($ua, "Windows CE") or
 stristr($ua, "AvantGo") or
 stristr($ua,"Mazingo") or
 stristr($ua, "Mobile") or
 stristr($ua, "T68") or
 stristr($ua,"Syncalot") or
 stristr($ua, "Blazer") ) {
 $DEVICE_TYPE="MOBILE";
 }
 if (isset($DEVICE_TYPE) and $DEVICE_TYPE=="MOBILE") {
 $location='mobile/index.php';
 header ('Location: '.$location);
 exit;
 }
 ?>
```